# what is better min-sdk version 2.3 or 3.0 for android fragment based app?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am creating an fragment based app So I want to know which one is better.If I choose 2.3 then what what problem will faced?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter: the [Android Support Library v4](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) includes full support for fragments on all API 4 (Android 1.6) and higher devices.

Answer (score 0):

You always have the information in your hands:

[Google oficial Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone)

Today april 10th version 2.3 or less are 6.8 % from 100% android. I think this is your answer.